# Multiply options for filter elements jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, filter

I have input whith user selection. It's number of rooms of objects.

```
<input class="roomInput" value="1" />
```

And have objects

```
<div class="object" data-rooms="1">1</div>
<div class="object" data-rooms="2">2</div>
<div class="object" data-rooms="3">3</div>
```

I use filter function to show/hide block by options. I do it like this:

```
        $(".submit").click(function() {
            
            // Get user option from input
            var $objectRooms = $('.roomInput').val();


            // Hide all objects
            $(".object").hide();
            $(".object").removeClass("show");
            
            

            // Show objects that match the filter 
            $('.object').filter(function() {
                if ($objectRooms == '0') {
                    return $(this).data('rooms') == '1' || $(this).data('rooms') == '2' || $(this).data('rooms') == '3' || $(this).data('rooms') == '4';
                } else {
                    return $(this).data('rooms') == $objectRooms;
                }

            }).addClass("show");



        });
```

But now i need to make it multiply. User can choose multiply paramters of rooms.

Comment: Please elaborate more on your problem

Comment: In roomInput may be more than one option. May <input class="roomInput" value="1, 2, 4" />. It's mean than user can find object with 1, 2, 4 rooms. Now user can filter objects only by one option 1 room or 2 room, etc

Comment: so your input will have values separated by commas ?